# Angular $rootScope init. ( Angular + Phonegap )

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Try create android app in phonegap, using android.

```
angular.module('myModule').config(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.internet = { status: 0, type: 'none'};
    document.addEventListener("offline", function(){
        $rootScope.internet.status = 0;
        $rootScope.internet.type = navigator.connection.type;
    }, false);
    document.addEventListener("online", function(){
        $rootScope.internet.status = 1;
        $rootScope.internet.type = navigator.connection.type;
    }, false);
  }]);
```

I only want to change global valiable, when navigator.connection changes, or go online/offline.

Or how can i bind `watch` to this `navigator.connection` global var.

Answer (score 0):

> You can't use `$rootScope` inside config phase of angular app, because it does gets created in `run` block which runs right after `.config` blocks end.

It does available from angular `run` phase. You could place this block of code inside the run phase.

You could use function and return `navigator.connection` value on each digest.

**Code**

```
angular.module('myModule').run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.internet = { status: 0, type: 'none'};
    document.addEventListener("offline", function(){
        $rootScope.internet.status = 0;
        $rootScope.internet.type = navigator.connection.type;
    }, false);
    document.addEventListener("online", function(){
        $rootScope.internet.status = 1;
        $rootScope.internet.type = navigator.connection.type;
    }, false);
    $rootScope.$watch(function(){
       return navigator.connection;
    }, function((newVal, oldVal){
       console.log(newVal)
    })
}]);
```

Comment: @ubombi does it help you?